TypeScript Property Decorators Throwing Error TS1240 on running code
Im working on a TypeScript project where I'm using property decorators to enforce validation on class properties. Here’s a simplified version of my code:
Note: Experimental decorators have been turned on in this project.
interface ValidatorConfig {
  [property: string]: {
    [validatableProp: string]: string[]; // ['required', 'positive']
  };
}

const registeredValidators: ValidatorConfig = {};

function Required(target: any, propName: string) { 
  registeredValidators[target.constructor.name] = {
    [propName]: ['required']
  };
}

function PositiveNumber(target: any, propName: string) {
  registeredValidators[target.constructor.name] = {
    [propName]: ['positive']
  };
}

function validate(obj: any): boolean {
  const objValidatorConfig = registeredValidators[obj.constructor.name];
  if (!objValidatorConfig) {
    return true;
  }

  let isValid = true;

  for (const prop in objValidatorConfig) {
    for (const validator of objValidatorConfig[prop]) {
      switch (validator) {
        case 'required':
          isValid = isValid && !!obj[prop];
          break;
        case 'positive':
          isValid = isValid && obj[prop] > 0;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
  return isValid;
}

class Course {
  @Required
  title: string;

  @PositiveNumber
  price: number;

  constructor(t: string, p: number) {
    this.title = t;
    this.price = p;
  }
}

const createCourse = new Course("Hello Book", 1000);

if (!validate(createCourse)) {
  alert('Invalid input, try again');
}

However, when I compile my code using 'tsc app.ts', I get the following errors:
app.ts:57:4 - error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'ClassFieldDecoratorContext<Course, string> & { name: "title"; private: false; static: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
57   @Required
~~~~~~~~
app.ts:59:4 - error TS1240: Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
Argument of type 'ClassFieldDecoratorContext<Course, number> & { name: "price"; private: false; static: false; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
59   @PositiveNumber
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
How can I resolve the TS1240 errors with my property decorators?

From the docs...

Decorators are a language feature which hasn’t yet been fully ratified into the JavaScript specification

You need to enable the experimentalDecorators option in your tsconfig.json.
If go to this TSPlayground, your code works as expected. Disable the experimentalDecorators option and it fails with the errors you mention above.
